# Constructing an n-node DAG, with exactly k paths between node 1 and node n

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

Pretty straight forward, yet I didn't find how to approach such a problem.
I tried constructing a solution from the reverse problem (Given a DAG count the number of paths between node 1 and node n), but It got me nowhere

Comment: How is $k$ related to $n$?

Comment: K and n are two indépendant variables

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume $1,2,\ldots,n$ are in topological order.

The solution is trivial for $n=1$ and doesn't exist for $n=2$ and $n=3$.

For $n=4$ use a transitive tournament and all paths: 14, 124, 134, 1234.

For $n>4$ take the solution for $n-1$ and apply it to vertices $2,\ldots,n$.  Then add edges 12 and 1$n$.

OOPS, as Ben Barber suggested this is just the solution for $k=n$.

Comment: And how do I decompose k into a sum of those numbers ? plus why do you think there's no solution for n = 2 and n = 3 ? we can take n = 3 and we have a solution for k = 1 (straight line 1-2-3), and k = 2 (the straight line plus an edge from node 1 to node 3), and the same answer for n = 2 and k = 1.

Comment: Are you assuming $k=n$?

Answer (score 0):

So why isn't anyone suggesting the obvious? k edges from 1 to vertices 2 through k+1, and then either a path from 2 to n, or all remaining edges from every other vertex to n?

Gerhard "Am I Not Understanding This?" Paseman, 2018.09.11.

Comment: And if all edges are needed to be directed, certainly there are tournaments which give the solution?  Gerhard "That Might Be Somewhat Harder" Paseman, 2018.09.11.

Comment: I don't quite understand but I suspect you are assuming $k\le n$. The number of paths can be as high as $2^{n-2}$.  Also there is only one tournament which is a DAG so it can't make many different path counts.